# Pass php var to Javascript from an ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I would create an ajax code that load a php page every x seconds.
Result: obtain a specific php var in the loaded page.
Then: assign the value of the obtained var to a javascript.

Comment: Too ambiguous, can you specify more?

Comment: Show your last code attempt. ;)

Comment: No code excerpt, unclear what you're asking (you seem to ask about client side then you comment about your problem being on server side...), not showing what you tried... -> vote to close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polling, in your case downloading a page every x seconds, is hardly ever the best approach to a problem. It wastes resources.

However, if you want to do something with Ajax, I suggest you use JQuery:

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get

An example, suppose you have a php 'test.php' file with:

```
echo $myVariable;
```

You can then do this in javascript:

```
$.get("test.php", function( data ) {
  alert( "The PHP variable is: "+data);
});
```

Combine this with a Javascript timer and you're done.

Comment: I've already tried this way, but how i can obtain the value of the php var?

Comment: Just echo the value in the file you load with get(). This value will become the data parameter of the function inside the get(). See my example above.

Comment: So if test.php  code is something like that <?php $test=1; echo $test; ?>  the value of "data" is 1 is right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. To transport more than one variable you would normally use json (http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php and http://www.json.org/js.html) to encode and decode, but for one variable you don't need to do that.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is perfect!